# Why isn't Jsclipper library behaving in same way as the Jsclipper Main demo?

Tags: javascript, svg, vector

The boolean operations in jsclipper.js gives a different result than the Main demo application for jsclipper.

I'm weirdly enough using exactly the same jsclipper code as the demo, since I downloaded the source code for jsclipper.js from the demo web page, to be sure.

```
var Subj=[[{"X":96.05815724969098,"Y":71.97971581634867},{"X":94.25101018863032,"Y":67.24637680924984},{"X":9.47273973638874,"Y":173.9797390387333}]];
var Clip=[[{"X":83.63036218081739,"Y":85.33308330559052},{"X":85.90175311733567,"Y":87.02908473311615},{"X":88.10438777004464,"Y":82.62343977750248}]];

//var Subj=[[{"x":-60.5122976050557,"y":31.98101279452465},{"x":-57.58064453087991,"y":28.623207223419882},{"x":-60.08743386861926,"y":29.44356552836135}]]
//var Clip=[{"x":-48.23331458158315,"y":-25.82931462303448},{"x":-50.91186400494968,"y":-25.356415428690656},{"x":-60.08743386861926,"y":29.44356552836135}]

var cpr = new ClipperLib.Clipper();

var clipType =  ClipperLib.ClipType.ctDifference;     
//var clipType =  ClipperLib.ClipType.ctIntersection;
//var clipType =  ClipperLib.ClipType.ctUnion; 

ClipperLib.JS.ScaleUpPaths(Subj, 1000);
ClipperLib.JS.ScaleUpPaths(Clip, 1000);

cpr.AddPaths(Subj, ClipperLib.PolyType.ptSubject, true);                        
cpr.AddPath(Clip, ClipperLib.PolyType.ptClip, true);     // add the paths

var solution_paths=[];

var subject_fillType = ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero;
var clip_fillType = ClipperLib.PolyFillType.pftNonZero;

var success = cpr.Execute(clipType, solution_paths, subject_fillType, clip_fillType);

ClipperLib.JS.ScaleDownPaths(solution_paths, 1000);

console.log('solution_paths '+JSON.stringify(solution_paths));
```

I'm using the same configuration for Filltypes and the same scaling etc. Even thou, it gives a different result.

The demo acts mathematically correct, but the library doesn't in my programming code.

The ctDifference operation should result in a solution consisting a 2D polygon with 6 vertices, but the jsclipper library generates a triangle instead.

All other operations, now commented, gives wrong result compared to the demo as well.

How do I make it act in the same way as the demo?

// Best Regards Jan-Olof Janson

Comment: Here is the link to the demo: http://jsclipper.sourceforge.net/6.2.1.1/main_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out what error I made.

I should have used

```
cpr.AddPaths(Clip, ClipperLib.PolyType.ptClip, true);     // add the paths
```

instead of

```
cpr.AddPath(Clip, ClipperLib.PolyType.ptClip, true);      // add the paths
```

The plural s is important, even thou I add only one path.

AddPath should also work if [path] is used, but for some reason I only get JSClipper to work if I use   [[Paths]]      ,arrays in a array.